# Error al crear una nueva instancia de clase en Java

Tags: java

Al crear una nueva instancia de mi clase en el main:

```
Coche miCoche = new Coche();

Me marca en rojo new Coche()
```

Me dice que

> el archivo no puede hacer referencia desde un contexto static.

Comment: tal vez tienes declarado public static class Coche si es asi, quita static, de lo contrario adjunta la declaración de la clase,para brindarte mas apoyo

Comment: class Coche {} así está declarada la clase

Comment: Si y no, entiendo lo que quiere decir e intento resolver con lo que ahí exponen pero no me funciona. Estoy haciendo un bootcamp, soy nuevo en esto y en el curso hacen exactamente lo mismo que yo hago y no les da el error cuando crean la instancia en el main aún cuando la clase no es static.